# After upgrading to .NET 6 assembly version isn't getting recognized

Tags: .net, vb.net

so in my *.vbproj I have set my Version number

```
...
<AssemblyVersion>2.0.0.0</AssemblyVersion>
...
```

and I'm trying to get it with following line and it returns **0.0.0.0**

`Private m_Version As String = Assembly.GetEntryAssembly().GetName().Version.ToString`

Is there other way to retrieve Assembly Version in .NET6?

Thanks

Comment: Do you still have an `AssemblyInfo.vb` file in your Project(s)? Is the Solution and its Projects correctly ported to the SDK-style? Have you previously created a package of some sort?